# Batch File To Detect And Set Windows 7 Power Mode

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch-file

I would like to create a batch file that checks the current system power mode and change it if necessary. I have the following. What am I doing wrong? (it does not work)

```
@ECHO OFF

SET _CURRENT_POWER_SCHEME = POWERCFG -GETACTIVESCHEME

IF NOT %_CURRENT_POWER_SCHEME% == "Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced)"(
    POWERCFG -SETACTIVE "381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e"

)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Think changing the power profile requires administrator privileges, have you tried running the batch file as admin?

Comment: @HaydnWVN Yes, even with admin privileges, the file executes and closes the window right-away. Even if I place PAUSE calls inside the IF statement and after it.

Comment: So a `PAUSE` before the `IF` still causes it to be closed?!

Comment: No, before the IF, the Pause works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience with batch file scripting, if it exits even when you have a PAUSE that should be getting hit, it means there is an error that causes it to crash.
In this case I think it's a few syntax issues, as well as how you are setting the variable.
I played around and got this to work:

```
@ECHO off
FOR /f "delims=" %%a in ('POWERCFG -GETACTIVESCHEME') DO @SET _CURRENT_POWER_SCHEME="%%a"
IF NOT %_CURRENT_POWER_SCHEME%=="Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced)" POWERCFG -SETACTIVE "381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e"
```

The "For /f..." line is usually the command I use to get the output of another command into a variable. It is normally for parsing through more complex responses, but it handles the -GETACTIVE command in this case. For more info on for loop syntax (or batch syntax in general): http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. I have had plenty of problems dealing with strings and command outputs using command-line. Sometimes it odd use of quotes (putting quotes around the variable used in polling the command, for example) The originial code, while logically sound, from when I was playing with it, would put the command as a string into the variable instead of the return.